# JUNO DS 61 RECORDING GUITAR

Tags: recording, keyboard

I just got the Juno DS-61 and was interested in recording some guitar licks directly on to the keyboard to use on the performance pads. I want to do this without a DAW or midi just DI into the keyboard. Is this possible? IF so how?

Comment: "Sample Import function to play samples (user Wav files) on the JUNO-DS keyboard" ... and 
"8 Phrase pads for triggering samples and songs previously stored as audio files on a USB stick" ... but then **"Intuitive 8 track pattern sequencer with non-stop loop recording function for a fast development of song ideas"** ... does that "loop recording" mean only MIDI sequences, or does it mean audio recording as well? Since you're the one who has the device, try it out and let us know.